# TextView restarts Marquee when changing another TextView in same LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, marquee

I have LinearLayout and inside 2 TextView both have marquee and when I update text in first then second TextView restarts marquee.

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/panel"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/first"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/second"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                      />
            </LinearLayout>
```

I found that if for `R.id.first` and `R.id.second` i set `layout_width="320dp"` the effect don't occurs.
But I want to set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` there is some workaround?

I found similar problem but without solution:
[Android, RelativeLayout restarts Marquee-TextView when changing ImageView in same RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203286/android-relativelayout-restarts-marquee-textview-when-changing-imageview-in-sam)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar problem and the solution IS to set fixed size for the Textview.

So why not do it progammatically? In my case, it solved the problem. Here is my solution in details :

The layout is a bit complex with a lot of changing values. Here is the interesting part :

layout.xml :

```
<!-- The height and visibility values change programatically -->
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <FrameLayout>
        ...
        // some code
        ...
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <!-- My scrolling textview. see below. -->
        <!-- The size will be set when -->
        <!-- the layout will be draw, -->
        <!-- after the Activity.onCreate(). -->
        <!-- I removed ALL THE UNECESSARY (I mean  -->
        <!-- scrollHorizontally, focusable and focusableInTouchMode. -->
        <!-- You don't need it !!!!) -->
        <fr.cmoatoto.android.widget.ScrollingTextView 
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" />

        <ImageView
            ...
            // some code
            ... />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The ScrollingTextView has been defined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2504840/1823503)

Here it is again :

ScrollingTextView.java :

```
public class ScrollingTextView extends TextView {

    public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScrollingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        if(focused)
            super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
        if(focused)
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFocused() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And finally the Activity. As I said before, You need to set fixed width and height so we will do it programmatically with a listener in the onCreate() :

MyActivity.java :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout);


    TextView textView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_trafic_text));
    textView.setText(getString(R.string.loading));
    textView.setEnabled(true); // Thanks to Romain Guy
    textView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,
                int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = right - left;
            params.height = bottom - top;
            params.weight = 0;
            v.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
}
```

Be careful if you need to change orientation or things like that but it works pretty well for me !

**----EDIT FOR PRE-API-11---**

Because `OnLayoutChangeListener` exists only from Api v11, there is a workaround (It works but I think it is less good) :

Remove the `OnLayoutChangeListener` from your activity :

MyActivity.java :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    TextView textView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_trafic_text));
    textView.setText(getString(R.string.loading));
    textView.setEnabled(true); // Thanks to Romain Guy
}
```

and add a `onSizeChanged` in your ScrollingTextView :

ScrollingTextView.java :

```
public class ScrollingTextView extends TextView {

    ...
    // Same code as before
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
        params.width = w;
        params.height = h;
        params.weight = 0;
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps !

Comment: I lost my morning and found this. Perfect!

Answer (score 13):

You should prevent putting both marquee in the same ViewGroup. In your case, you can wrap each marquee TextView with a LinearLayout (this won't work if using RelativeLayout).

Comment: Best answer. Easiest and most logical way to solve the problem. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This totally works. I just put my `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 4):

just a simple Fix..:) no need to worry much...just fix width of textview as some 800dp or too higher width. it will solve reset issue

Comment: You saved my life. Just set the width of the TextView with a specific number of dp instead of using `wrap_content`.